# Fragment vs Activity canvas drawing on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, canvas

I designed a surfaceview, where it's canvas is drawn using a thread (Game loop). The Game loop draws 300 small images.

If I load this surfaceview on activity, the time to execute a frame is 5- 10 ms lower than if I load it on a fragment (withing an activity).

Test results
300 images loop- activity (24 millsec) , Fragment (32 millsec).

What is the reason behind this? How can I improve the performance in Fragment?

Here is my code. The loop at the end is the bottleneck. *clusters*  list could have 300 items to draw.

```
public List<PCluster> clusters = new ArrayList<PCluster>();

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    try {
        if (canvas == null) {
            return;
        }
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(backColor);
        if (waitTillLoad) {
            return;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    final int savedState = canvas.save();
    try {

        minX = (int) (((viewWidth / mScaleFactor) - Gen.screenSizeWidth) / 2) * Utils.VIEW_SIZE;
        minY = (int) (((viewHeight / mScaleFactor) - Gen.screenSizeHeight) / 2) * Utils.VIEW_SIZE;

        if (mPosX > maxX) {
            mPosX = maxX;
        }
        if (mPosX < minX) {
            mPosX = minX;
        }
        if (mPosY > maxY) {
            mPosY = maxY;
        }
        if (mPosY < minY) {
            mPosY = minY;
        }


        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (!showBackground) {

            for (PCluster cluster : clusters) {
                if (cluster.isVisible) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(cluster.Picture, cluster.BoardLocation.left,
                            cluster.BoardLocation.top, null);
                }
            }
            Log.d("myApp", "   " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
```

This is main activity layout.  @+id/fragment is used to load the layout below     which has `SurfaceView` `LinearLayout` where the surface view is inserted at run time and where the drawing happens.

Main Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_fake"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fragment"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_ad"/>

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    class="controllers.AdFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Game Layout with surface view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/gamesettingpanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/gameoption_panel" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/scorepanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    layout="@layout/scorepanel" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/chaetpanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    layout="@layout/gamecheat_panel" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/finishpanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/finishedpanel" />
```

Comment: I think that [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will greatly increase your chances to get a meanigful answer

Comment: Can you post a fully functional example? I think it's possible to get a better result with a custom view, keeping reusability without losing that much performance, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: What do you mean by custom view. I thought Surface View suppose to improve performance and UI experience. I moved to surface view from normal canvas drawing because of that.

Comment: Can you please post your xml with fragment container and fragment layout?

Comment: I have added layouts now, Thanks